# How to prevent of sending empty fields in Angular HttpClient.post method?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

when I want to send information as post Method to my Rest API, Angular sends empty fields and subsequently, my database saves the empty value.

But I want to prevent it and I don't want to send empty fields from my Angular to my Backends.

For example, in below example, Angular sends an "" in entityTypeName field and unfortunately, the Postgres DB will save empty instead of null.

```
{ 
   createdAt: "2019-01-11T13:59:52.311678"
   entityTypeName: ""
   id: "1bd46fce-fc6f-410f-acaf-74d5964cf92b"
   updatedAt: "2019-01-11T13:59:52.311678"
   updatedBy: "admin@admin.com"
   version: 0 
}
```

I'm looking for a general solution that prevent sending empity values in Angular side in all situations.

Comment: There isn't a general solution. You either make sure that client is sending valid requests, validate them on the backend before acting on them, or (ideally) both. You need a rule somewhere that says that `""` is not a valid value for `entityTypeName`.

Comment: Thanks, but so sad.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function doing it. Simply provide your object to the function, and it will delete the empty keys.

```js
function removeEmptyStringsFrom(obj) {
  const clone = { ...obj };
  Object.entries(clone).forEach(([key, val]) => val === '' && delete clone[key]);
  return clone;
}

const test = {
  notEmpty: 'toto',
  empty: '',
};

console.log(removeEmptyStringsFrom(test));
```

EDIT : Challenge accepted !

```js
const removeEmptyStringsFrom = (obj) => Object
  .entries({ ...obj })
  .filter(([key, val]) => val !== '')
  .reduce((prev, curr) => ({ ...prev, [curr[0]]: curr[1] }), {});

const test = {
  notEmpty: 'toto',
  empty: '',
};
    
console.log(removeEmptyStringsFrom(test));
```

Comment: This will drop **falsey** properties from an object.

Comment: @cgTag well that's kind of what I said ...

Comment: Just change `!val` to `val !== ""` and you've got what the OP wants :)

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you can rewrite `removeEmptyFieldsFrom()` as one line of code. I've been unable to figure that out in JS. I wish we had `Object.zip()`

Comment: I'm waiting for my upvote then :)

Comment: @cgTag (although it's not technically on one line, I find it cleaner like that, for readability's sake)

Comment: A reducer! Oh very impressive. I am humbled by the better JS coder :)

Comment: `{ ...prev, [curr[0]]: curr[1] }` blows my mind. I did not know you could use an accessor with deconstruction. thank you.

Comment: Why thank you, and I'm glad I could make you learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide any kind of example i am going to base my answer on the assumptions that you pass an instance of an object (lets name it `entity`) in the body and you let the HttpClient handle the serialisation to json.

If you want to get rid of properties with the empty string you could delete the property

```
delete entity.entityTypeName
```

For a generic solution that would remove all empty string properties, you could use an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) that would

- check if the outgoing httpRequest holds a json body
- iterate through all the properties (or specific properties)
- delete those that are declared as empty strings